# Error al obtener el rol de un usuario logeado en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, phpmyadmin, mariadb, laragon

Intento obtener el rol para mostrarlo en el panel del usuario una vez logeado pero me encuentro con el sgte error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que en el panel(dashboard) del usuario una vez logueado se muestre el rol y su nombre en la parte derecha superior. Hasta el momento solo me funciona el nombre del usuario. Aqui dejo la imagen de ejemplo que quiero realizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la relacion que tienen las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modelo `User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\UserResetPassword; 

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password','role_id','password',
    ];

  
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function rol(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class,'role_id','id');
    }

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new UserResetPassword($token));
    }
}
```

mi modelo `Role.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model

{

    protected $table='roles';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public $timestamps=false;

    //campos que se pueden modificar
    protected $fillable=[
        'nombre'
    ];

    public function User(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Este es la vista del panel del usuario cuando se logea y es donde muestro el nombre del usuario y me funciona correctamente pero no he podido mostrar el rol  `admin.blade.php`

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
           <small class="bg-green">
<!--aqui es donde tengo el codigo para mostrar el rol pero me sale el error-->
                   {{ auth()->user()->rol()->nombre}}
            </small>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">
                <!--aqui si me muestra el nombre del usuario correctamente-->
                            {{ auth()->user()->name }}
                     </span>
 </a>
```

Este es el controlador pero aqui solo tengo las funciones de crud que muestran en la opcion de gestionar usuarios. `UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserFormRequest;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = User::with('rol')
            ->where('role_id', '=', '2')->where('role_id', '=', '3')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('seguridad.usuario.index', ["usuarios" => $usuarios]);

    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('seguridad.usuario.create');
    }

    public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
    {
        $usuario          = new User;
        $usuario->name    = $request->get('name');
        $usuario->email   = $request->get('email');
        $usuario->role_id = $request->rol;

        //bcrypt es para encriptar la contraseña
        $usuario->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $usuario->save();

        return Redirect::to('seguridad/usuario')->with('message', 'Usuario creado correctamente');;

    }

    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view("seguridad.usuario.edit", ["usuario" => User::findOrFail($id)]);

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //filtra los datos del usuario por el id
        $usuario           = User::findOrFail($id);
        $usuario->name     = $request->get('name');
        $usuario->role_id  = 1;
        $usuario->email    = $request->get('email');
        $usuario->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $usuario->update();
        return Redirect::to('seguridad/usuario')->with('message', 'Actualizado correctamente');

    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $usuario = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
        return Redirect::to('seguridad/usuario');

    }

}
```

Comment: @BetaM son 3: Administrador, Cobrador y supervisor.

Comment: @BetaM los formularios de registros tienen reglas de validacion, entonces no me permite duplicar porque los campos usuario y email son unicos.

Comment: @BetaM Correcto, pero ademas el nombre del usuario y este si me funciona.

Comment: @BetaM por que en esa rutas es donde me muestra los usuarios. Y en este caso solo quiero que el rol admin pueda ver solo esos dos roles: Cobrador y supervisor. No qieo que se muestren los usuarios con rol admin.

Comment: En el controlador, estas usando get o first?? Para obtener la data del usuario? Como es el usuario logueado debería ser first si estad usando get deberías tener un foreach en el blade

Comment: @VKozisck Ya actualice la pregunta y agrege el controlador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione en modificar esto: `{{ auth()->user()->rol()->nombre}}`

por esto:  `{{ auth()->user()->role->nombre}}`

Answer (score 1):

Para generar la consulta deseada considera las siguientes observaciones:

- Primero haces una carga ambiciosa del usuario con su relación `rol`
- En lugar de hacerlo en la vista, puedes filtrar directo en la consulta por el id del usario que se esta intentando loguear
- No tiene caso hacer un ordenamiento de los usuarios obtenidos, por que de hecho solo vas a recuperar 1 (*el que esta intentando iniciar sesión*)
- Si solo quieres obtener el rol con el que accedio, entonces no ocupas 2 `where` sino solamente 1 y ahi es donde buscarás comparar con el valor que te llegue del formulario para identificar que rol eligio
- En lugar de get que nos regresaría una colección, usarás findOrFail para solo retornar un objeto de Usuario

Consulta:

```
 $usuarios = User::with('rol')->whereRolId(2)->findOrFail(auth()->id());
```

*Asumiendo por ejemplo que 2 es el id del usuario admin*, en caso de que se quiera acceder por el nombre del rol y no por su id entonces la consulta deberá modificarse.

Entonces como solamente estamos obteniendo 1 objeto de usuario podemos acceder a sus atributos de esta forma:

Para obtener el nombre del usuario logueado:

```
{{ $usuarios->name }}
```

Para obtener el nombre del rol con el que inició sesión:

```
foreach ($usuarios->rol as $rol) {
    {{ $rol->nombre }}
}
```

Comment: Creo que no me entendistes. La consulta que esta en el controlador solo se genera cuando estoy en el panel de administrador en la gestion de usuarios. Yo lo que quiero es que me muestre el rol del usuario logeado en el panel de ese usuario y me lo muestre en parte susperior derecha.

Comment: Y la última línea que coloqué da eso precisamente el nombre del rol del usuario que inició la sesión

Comment: me sale error igual forma: Property [rol] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\laragon\www\prestamos\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\prestamos\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php)

Comment: Si sale eso es que entonces esta obteniendo mas de un rol dejame modificar

Comment: Igual me sale error. Undefined variable: rol (View: C:\laragon\www\prestamos\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\prestamos\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php). Hay que mirar de como traer el rol porque asi siempre genera error

Comment: Daré una revisada y editare ok?

Comment: Mira ya modifique la pregunta para que me comprendan mejor